# How can I find the name/location of an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a number of files under version control with SVN, and I'm trying to switch to [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29). However, it has been a long time since I made the repository, and I have forgotten its URL.

Is there some way to get the URL of the Subversion repository associated with a given file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like:

```
svn info <file>
```

Run this on a given checked out file from the repository. It should give you more information about the file status and the repository URL.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following command: `svn info`